# TestNG, Multiple duplicate listener warnings on implementing multiple listener interfaces

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a single Listener class that implements `IAnnotationTransformer, IInvokedMethodListener, ITestListener and IReporter`.

My Test run successfully **BUT** i get a warning `"[TestNG] [WARN] Ignoring duplicate listener : com.NGtest.RetryListener"`. This warning is shown for every method call i.e. Listener gets called multiple times per test method invocation, and hence the **IGNORED duplicate warning**.

- How to stop this warning from showing?
- It is noted that if i remove the `IReporter` implementation then the warning is gone.
- If i create different classes for each listener implementation then the warning is gone.
- However, the plan was to have a single class implementing all the listeners. Is it possible?
- How to solve this warning? Is this warning something to be concerned about? How can i stop this warning from showing?

**Listener Class:**

```
public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer, IInvokedMethodListener, ITestListener, IReporter {
    .....implemented methods for interface ....
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class RetryProvider {
    @Test (dataProvider = "datasource")
    public void Test1(int code, String type, ITestContext context){
        System.out.println("Test1(): " + code + " : " + type);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "datasource")
    public Object[][] getData(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[3][2];
        data[0][0] = 1;
        data[0][1] = "apple";
        data[1][0] = 2;
        data[1][1] = "mango";
        data[2][0] = 1;
        data[2][1] = "guava";
        return data;
    }       
}
```

**Test Xml:**

```
...<suite name="NGBug Suite">
    <listeners><listener class-name="com.NGtest.RetryListener" /></listeners>
    <test name="NGBug Test"><classes><class name="com.NGtest.RetryProvider" /></classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Test Result:**

```
[TestNG] [WARN] Ignoring duplicate listener : com.NGtest.RetryListener
[TestNG] [WARN] Ignoring duplicate listener : com.NGtest.RetryListener
[TestNG] [WARN] Ignoring duplicate listener : com.NGtest.RetryListener
Test1(): 1 : apple
Test1(): 2 : mango
Test1(): 3 : guava
```

Comment: What version of TestNG are you using?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, I am using TestNG 6.11.

Comment: The problem originates with this commit: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/commit/9393c688aaa027a4e4dfa56cd70dfabc44db81b3 If you really want to get this fixed, best to raise an issue at the TestNG GitHub project.

Comment: Thank you @RobbyCornelissen for your time. I have raised the problem at TestNG GitHub [https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1400](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1400)

Comment: @BipoK - Please refer to my comment in the bug that you logged. Please share a sample test that I can execute to recreate the problem.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan, done. have updated [https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1400](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1400) with the sample.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan, one last question. Since there is a `WARNing`, Is there something to be concerned about if i continue to implement multiple listeners in the same class **OR** do you recommend separate class for each Listener i want to implement. Warning is shown only when i include `IReporter `  as one of the interfaces. Thanks again.

Comment: @BipoK - I don't think there should be any problem. But that being said, I would recommend that you have multiple listener implementations which target a specific Listener. That way you are will to wire them separately as and however you need.